# How to separate scraping results after using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from NJR, http://www.njrsurgeonhospitalprofile.org.uk/HospitalProfile?hospitalName=Abergele%20Hospital

I am at a point where I am getting the correct values, however, I am having trouble getting the values in their respective groups.

If you open the link above, then click on the '12-month practice profile' dropdown, you can see the different 'operation types'. I would like to have each row be its specific group.

As of now, my code will collect all the information but it is not separated into its specific group. In fact, in trying to understand my code more, it is just pulling all strings found in between  which may not be specific enough.

Either I am pulling the data incorrectly, or I need to figure out a way to separate the results into the appropriate groups.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("http://www.njrsurgeonhospitalprofile.org.uk/HospitalProfile?hospitalName=Abergele%20Hospital")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find_all(["div"],{"class":"toggle_container"})[1]
print(all)
```

up to this point, I am able to parse out the appropriate HTML code which has all the necessary data. Next I iterate over all the "td" objects.

```
i=0
for item in all.find_all("td"):
    print(all.find_all("td")[i].text)
    i=i+1
print("done")
```

Results:

```
Hip Primary
-
208
220
Hip Revision
-
Fewer Than 5
25
Knee Primary
Patello-Femoral Replacement
Fewer Than 5
4
Knee Primary
Total knee replacement
211
230
Knee Primary
Unicondylar Knee Replacement
20
26
Knee Revision
-
5
16
Shoulder Primary
-
15
16
       Total

459+
537
done
```

Realistically, I don't want the national averages or the total row. But I can figure that out later.

Comment: What do you mean you want to group them together? Isn't the output in order already?

Comment: I am trying to make a dataset where the first 4 rows from my results equates to 1 row on my dataset.

Operation Type | Operation Subcategory | Procedures recorded | avg \n
Hip Primary       | -                                     | 208                            | 220

Comment: maybe you zip the values with table head as keys into dictionary first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient answer to your problem but you could create an empty list (i.e. `all_rows`) which is going to contain lists which have lengths of 4 items.

```
temp = list()
all_rows = list()
for item in all.find_all('td'):
    temp.append(item.text)
    i += 1
    if i % 4 == 0:
        all_rows.append(temp)
        temp = []
```

Which gives the output of:

```
[
  ['Hip Primary', '-', '208', '220'],
  ['Hip Revision', '-', 'Fewer Than 5', '25'],
  ['Knee Primary', 'Patello-Femoral Replacement', 'Fewer Than 5', '4'],
  ['Knee Primary', 'Total knee replacement', '211', '230'],
  ['Knee Primary', 'Unicondylar Knee Replacement', '20', '26'],
  ['Knee Revision', '-', '5', '16'],
  ['Shoulder Primary', '-', '15', '16'],
  ['\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Total', '', '459+', '537']
]
```

Then you could possibly store all this inside of a dictionary, where your key is index 0, and your values are lists of the remaining 3 items in the lists. Like this:

```
all_rows_dict = dict()
for l in all_rows:
    all_rows_dict[l[0]] = l[1::]
```

This gives output of:

```
{
 'Hip Primary': ['-', '208', '220'],
 'Hip Revision': ['-', 'Fewer Than 5', '25'],
 'Knee Primary': ['Unicondylar Knee Replacement', '20', '26'],
 'Knee Revision': ['-', '5', '16'],
 'Shoulder Primary': ['-', '15', '16'],
 '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Total': ['', '459+', '537']
}
```

Then to remove all those non-breaking spaces you could create a clean dictionary like this:

```
clean_dict = {key.replace(u'\xa0', u''): value for key, value in all_rows_dict.items()}
```

With the final output being:

```
{
 'Hip Primary': ['-', '208', '220'],
 'Hip Revision': ['-', 'Fewer Than 5', '25'],
 'Knee Primary': ['Unicondylar Knee Replacement', '20', '26'],
 'Knee Revision': ['-', '5', '16'],
 'Shoulder Primary': ['-', '15', '16'],
 'Total': ['', '459+', '537']
}
```

Comment: This gets the job done. I was considering tweaking the code to scrape the data but this does the same. Thanks!